# Chat search should ignore the rendered html and focus on the markdown

Tags: feature-request, chat, search

Just [search "code" in the chat search](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=code&room=89). You will immediately that [this](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=406392#406392) will show up, but hey, where does it says "code" in that string? Well, apparently you are searching the HTML version of the string, to be more accurate:

```
<code>!.is()</code> != <code>.not()</code>
```

This is unexpected, and sometimes screws what you expect to show up wasting your time. Can the search be changed so it ignores the rendered html and search based on the markdown version of the message?